# libevent, start SSL after

Tags: c, ssl, libevent

I need to set up a TCP socket and send a message to the server and then do SSL negotiation with the server and do the subsequent data exchange in SSL. I need to use libevent to implement this because it's non blocking so I can have many connections at the same time.

I can get the connection set up and exchange some data in clear text:

```
struct bufferevent *bev = bufferevent_socket_new(base, -1, BEV_OPT_CLOSE_ON_FREE);
struct sockaddr_in addr; 
//fill the addr with ip and port
bufferevent_socket_connect(bev, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr_in));
//send data
evbuffer_add(bufferevent_get_output(bev), data, len);
```

The problem is, libevent seems to only have one API to do SSL, but it assumes bufferevent object is not created yet.

```
bufferevent_openssl_socket_new
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

Found a workaround by freeing the existing one (clear text) and create a new one. The trick is to save the fd of the old before destroying the bufferevent.

```
//save the fd in the old bufferevent (cleartext)
fd = bufferevent_getfd(cb->bev);
bufferevent_setfd(cb->bev, -1);
bufferevent_free(cb->bev);

bev = bufferevent_openssl_socket_new(base, fd, ssl,
    BUFFEREVENT_SSL_CONNECTING,
    BEV_OPT_CLOSE_ON_FREE|BEV_OPT_DEFER_CALLBACKS);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try use bufferevent_openssl_filter_new() to wrap an existing bufferevent directly, instead create another bufferevent from the raw socket fd

`/**
 * Create a new SSL bufferevent to send its data over another bufferevent.
 *
 * @param base An event_base to use to detect reading and writing.  It
 *   must also be the base for the underlying bufferevent.
 * @param underlying A socket to use for this SSL
 * @param ssl A SSL* object from openssl.
 * @param state The current state of the SSL connection
 * @param options One or more bufferevent_options
 * @return A new bufferevent on success, or NULL on failure
 */
struct bufferevent *
bufferevent_openssl_filter_new(struct event_base *base,
    struct bufferevent *underlying,
    struct ssl_st *ssl,
    enum bufferevent_ssl_state state,
    int options);`